# passing parameters from a table in main report to subreport

Tags: jasper-reports, subreport

I want to pass field of table in main report to subreport as a parameter in *JasperReports*

```xml
<jasperReport xmlns ---- >
    <subDataset name="tableDataset" >
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[{select * from person]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="ID" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    </subDataset>
        <title>
            <jr:table >
                <jr:column width="133" >
                    <jr:detailCell >
                        <textField>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{ID}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </jr:detailCell>
                </jr:column>
                ---
                --
                </jr:table>
        </title>
        <summary>
                <subreport>
<subreportParameter name="ID">
                <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$F{ID}]]>     </subreportParameterExpression>
            </subreportParameter>
                    <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                    <subreportExpression><![CDATA["phonemumbers.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
                </subreport>


        </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

I passed parameter to subreport as above but getting error as field not found

Answer (score 0):

The way you are passing the field as parameter from main report to subreport is correct. But you cannot use this parameter directly in subreport. You have to first **capture the parameter in subreport** and then use it. Add following line to your **subreport** (just after `<import>`'s and before `<queryString>`):

```
<parameter name="ID" class="java.lang.Integer" isForPrompting="false"/>
```

Now use it in subreport as:

```
$P{ID}
```

Comment: is it possible to pass parameter from table main report to sub report table

Comment: I didn't understand what you want exactly. Please edit your question accordingly.